# Reversing a random amount of numbers

Tags: java, reverse, joptionpane

I have this code:

```
int rev=0;
int opt=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers do you need?"));
for (int i=0; i<numbers; i++) {
   int numbers=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add your numbers"));
   while (numbers != 0) {
      rev=rev*10;
      rev=rev+numbers%10;
      numbers=numbers/10;
    }
 }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are "+rev);
```

It works perfectly fine. I want the numbers to be reversed though. It does, but it has to be multiple numbers.

**Example:** Let's say I want 2 numbers: `123`,`456` the output would be `321654`

My question is, if I want 3 numbers: `1`,`2`,`3`  how do i make it so it would print `321` because it doesn't work if I add one digit numbers.

I'm sorry if it doesn't make sense or my question doesn't explain much.

Comment: These two algorithms are completely _different_. In the first case you take the two number, reverse each one, and concat them _in the original order_. In the second case you concat them in _reverse order_. What are the rules here? What happens if I have `123, 1, 2, 3, 456`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I mentioned it. I want the second one. What I meant to say was that it only works correctly in the first one. `123, 1, 2, 3, 456` would be `456, 3, 2, 1, 123`

Comment: Just use [`Collections.reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (Its not tested)

```
 String res="";
 Integer opt=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers do you need?"));
 for (int i=0; i<opt; i++) {
   String numbers=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add your numbers");
   res = new StringBuilder(numbers).reverse().toString() + res;
 }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are "+res);
```

Or this

```
 String res="";
 Integer opt=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many numbers do you need?"));
 for (int i=0; i<opt; i++) {
   String numbers=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add your numbers");
   res += numbers;
 }
 String reversedString = new StringBuilder(res).reverse().toString();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are "+ reversedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You COULD put those numbers in an ArrayList and then use Collections.reverse(list) to get them in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse each item's inner character order and then reverse the order in which the items were provided to you.

```
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> reversedNumbers = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    for (/*your for loop condition here...*/) {
        String sNumber = /*ask the user for a string here...*/
        StringBuilder reversedNumber = new StringBuilder(sNumber).reverse();
        reversedNumbers.add(reversedNumber);
    }
    Collections.reverse(reversedNumbers);/*finally reverse the colection*/
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are "+ reversedNumbers);
```